# What is the difference between a need, a drive, and a motive?

Tags: motivation

Going by Hull's drive-reduction theory, as stated in *Psychology*, by Ciccarelli, 4th edition:

> A need is a requirement of some material (such as food or water) that is essential for survival of the organism. When an organism has a need, it leads to a psychological tension as well as a physical arousal that motivates the organism to act in order to fulfill the need and reduce the tension. This tension is called a drive (Hull, 1943).

In the abstract of Mahatoo's (1989) paper, "Motives must be Differentiated from Needs, Drives, Wants: Strategy Implications", the following is stated:

> In a suggested model, motives are suggested as the specific motivational element that directs the consumer′s drive towards a particular response. Thus while needs generate the response tendency, motives determine the specific behavioural action.

What I'm inferring from these two sources of information is that:

1) **Need is a physiological/psychological requirement**

2) **Drive is what propels the organism to eliminate imbalance**

3) **Motive is the course of action the organism takes when faced with a drive.**

An example of point 3 could be the instance where a recuperating substance abuse addict feels the drive to relapse, they may not with the help of proper clinical intervention if their motive is to achieve sobriety.

My question: Am I correct? If not, I would appreciate it if you could post the correction, both for the differences and the example.

Answer (score 1):

The sources and the theory you mentioned are quite old and may be outdated. I learned about drives, needs and motives in a more modern context during my introductory course of Industrial and Organizational (I/O) Psychology. Overall drives are more of a non-human concept that is too simplistic to explain complex human behavior (Landy & Conte, 2013). Nowadays, the definitions below are often used by psychologists.

According to Buchanan and Hyczynski (2013) a **need** is innate and related to survival such as the need for water, oxygen etc. Needs that are triggered by deprivation are known as **drives**.

Buchanan and Hyczynski (2013) use the following description of a **motive**:

> A socially acquired need activated by a desire for fulfilment.

Drives and motives can be contrasted using the information provided by Buchanan and Huczynski (2013):
*Drives*
 1. are innate
 2. have a physiological basis
 3. are activated by deprivation
 4. are aimed at satiation

*Motives*
 1. are learned
 2. have a social basis
 3. are activated by environment
 4. are aimed at stimulation

I know I somewhat glossed over the theory you mentioned but I looked it up and it seems somewhat outdated to me. I hope this more recent information helps answering your question!

Further reading:
Landy, F.J. & Conte, J.M. (2013). Work in the 21st century: An introduction to industrial and organizational psychology (6th edition). New York: McGraw-Hill. (Chapter 8)
Buchanan, D. & Huczynski, A. (2013). Organizational behavior: An introductory text (8th edition). Essex, UK: Pearson Education. (Chapter 9)

Answer (score -2):

In this context, motive does not refer to an overarching goal, but rather, a more immediate one. Judging from the excerpts you provided, here is an example:

1) My body **needs** nutrients in order to survive.
2) This need results in psychological and physiological discomfort, AKA a **drive**: hunger.
3) As a result of my hunger, I order take-out. My **motive** for doing this is that I want food.

The way I conceptualize the distinctions is that it goes need-> drive -> motive -> resulting action.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE I am not the person who downvoted your answer, but we do work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be backed up with reliable references so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's/answerer's background. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.